# This (multiple meaning fitting into a context)

Tags: meaning-in-context

> One glance at it told me all I needed to know. I saw you running along **this** passageway and out of sight.

Context - Snape is now at a secret place which he found out about when he was in the office and saw a map upon which he possibly saw the passage and all.

My research :
Now "this" here could either mean:

1. "This" as in the passage I got through to reach this house and consequently the room.
   Or
2. He is using "this" like we do when giving account of a past event like "Yesterday, I saw **this** girl.

Which one is correct?
**And more importantly, how do you determine that?**

Comment: I don't understand your confusion - both of your examples rely entirely on context to identify which <thing> is being referred to. Your main example could refer to a current location, or could refer to a location being pointed at on a map, but apparently both are actually the same thing at that point in time!

Comment: Because "non-specific" *I met **this** girl yesterday* (with the girl not present, and not having been mentioned earlier in the conversation) is an extremely "slangy / colloquial" usage, it's almost inconceivable that someone like Hogwart's Professor Severus Snape would use it like that. So you can be pretty certain your first interpretation is correct. In other contexts, the clue might be in the fact that the speaker looks or points at ***this** [whatever]* as he speaks.

Comment: Do you mean this? INFORMAL
used in speech to draw attention to someone or something.
"I turned round and there was this big mummy standing next to us!"

Comment: Why are you asking "Do **I** mean that?" That's exactly the usage involved in your second interpretation above (where ***some*** is often interchangeable for ***this***), but I'm just saying there's no chance that would apply to Snape's speech.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand it now.  P.S I didn't mean to be rude, I was just confirming. Thank you again!

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude either. But even though the colloquial use of ***this*** doesn't actually apply here, it seems you didn't fully understand that usage until now. I say that because it looks like you didn't originally recognise both your "girl" and your "mummy" examples as being the same usage. But you know it now.

Comment: You are right! Thanks!